# Does the mean and standard deviation need to be reported when writing up the simple effects analysis of a ANOVA interaction?

Tags: anova

I'm currently carrying out a four-way mixed factorial ANOVA and in the process of writing up the results. I've done simple effects analysis on all the significant interactions between the factors, however I have noticed that the output doesn't include standard deviations.

I've had a look at past research and it seems that sometimes the means and SD's are reported when writing up the post hoc tests but sometimes they aren't.

This is how I have reported the findings so far in which I've just left gaps for where I thought the SD's should go (if they are needed) ...

Simple effects analysis revealed that Corrugator activity was only significantly higher when facial stimuli was exposed for 56ms during the empathic narrative condition (M = 2.88, SD = …) compared to the control narrative condition (M = -1.4, SD = …), F(32) = 4.77, p = .04, η2 = 1.3 (see Figure 1)

If I do need to include SD's how do I go about including them in the analysis as there is no option (that I am aware of) that allows SD's to be in the simple effects outputs? Will I have to do subsequent analysis to find out?

Thank you for any help that you might be able to provide!

Emma

Comment: What program are you using? Also, please specify the field you are working in.
That said, I would always incluse SD and mean in an analysis - it gives the reader a better idea how your data work. But this can , in my field, be done in a different table.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find results sections filled with (P=0.03, m=3, sd=5, etc) to be hard to read and rather pointless. Put the summary stats in a table, not the text, unless you are pointing out something about them. Eg "the variance was consistent with that seen in previous studies (sd=5)". If you find it difficult to figure out what should be going into the results section instead it may be helpful to read older papers, this one has a pretty nice results section:

> Avery O, MacLeod C, McCarty M (1944). ["Studies on the Chemical Nature
>   of the Substance Inducing Transformation of Pneumococcal Types:
>   Induction of Transformation by a Desoxyribonucleic Acid Fraction
>   Isolated from Pneumococcus Type Iii"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2135445/pdf/137.pdf). J Exp Med 79 (2): 137–158.

Anyway, all the data should be included in your report so others can analyze it for themselves. Our data is much more important and relevant to future workers than our opinions about it. Also, the shape of the data may include important hints about what is going on.